# How delete hover effect with css

Tags: css

I'm not good with css.
I would delete this behavior:
When i pass my mouse overe an immage i obtain a black square , as you can see:

[image]

I want to delete this effect.
I would pass the mouse over the image and doesn't show nothing over the it.
thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The css pseudo-class for when the mouse is hovering is :hover. I guess you should write something like:

```
.selector:hover{
    background:none;
}
```

Comment: perfect i used: a:hover{
    background:none;
}

and it works

Comment: You are actually allowed to flag an answer as "having answered your question" ;-)

Comment: i have to wait time. I'll do :)